# Does .Net Core generate the same IL as standard .Net?

Tags: .net, .net-core

We have [this announcement](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNET5IsDeadIntroducingASPNETCore10AndNETCore10.aspx) that .Net Core is being renamed to 1.0 (confusing, but fine, whatever). In it Hanselman states

> It doesn't yet support VB or F#.

which makes me think that I'm missing something. My logic works as follows.

Take two simple simple Hello World apps one in C#, the other in VB. Assuming you kept it simple, when compiling with standard MSBuild/.NET framework you should get identical IL. It is my understanding that you can then get .Net core to run that same dll since it's all IL at that level. So why say that it doesn't support VB? Is it that it doesn't support it beyond simple situations (where you'd likely reference VB-specific stuff)? Or is it that the actual IL generated when compiling for .Net Framework versus .NET Core is different and there isn't a VB/F# compiler around yet?

Comment: probably because those languages have language specific reference dlls (eg Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll) which have their own references that don't support core.

Comment: @Jeff well yeah but I covered that in the question - you don't *have* to use `Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll` in a vb app (and you can use it fine in a c# one either). So its either that this dll hasn't been moved to .Net Core but the IL is identical and its not quite correct that vb-wont-work, or the actual IL is different. Which is it?

Comment: There is only one kind of IL, the .NETCore version is not different.  Your assumption that Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll is not necessary is not accurate, the compiler auto-generates code that uses it.  Basic stuff, like string comparison which needs to observe Option Compare.  Much the same for F# and FSharp.Core.dll

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it generates the same IL

(I could not resist to answer it that simple)

Nevertheless, to the VB Part: In regards of VB support: Running on .NET Core requires a compiler (implemented in Roslyn), a CLI command `dotnet-compile-vb` (not implemented ... for F# the community delivered it by now) and a supported version of `Microsoft.VisualBasic` (implemented in corefx). I guess the point of VisualBasic support is the same as for e.g. ASP.NET SignalR. The code is 95% there, it runs, but it is not officially tested and supported. It is a matter of timelines not of technologies.

IMHO: Considering that the `Microsoft.VisualBasic` assembly is there and the IL is the same, it could in theory even execute a compiled VB assembly as long as the compiler used the System.Runtime based Core platform.

PS May 2019: they just announced to Port the majority of the VB .NET Runtime