# .NET Core vs standard .NET library performance

Tags: .net, dll, .net-core

Is there any difference in performance for the same code compiled into standard .NET library or .NET core on Windows?

I suppose that speed would be same if [same IL is generated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34906969/does-net-core-generate-the-same-il-as-standard-net). And what about memory requirements?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

.Net Standard are only interfaces what can be implemented in .Net Core, .Net Framework or other. For more i recommend to read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/standard/library

If you want to know differencces about .Net Core and .Net Framework (it's not "standard .Net") you can see https://www.techempower.com/benchmarks/