# When a ".Net Standard" project is built - what does that mean?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, .net-standard

Since .net standard is not an implementation, it's just a set of rules, what happens when a .net standard Class-Library project is built?

I would think that one could only build a .net framework or .net core (etc.) project (which can include a .net standard class-library's **files**). And yet it is possible to completely build a .net standard class library as a project.

Comment: @JeremyCaney very unclear what you trying to prevent/advice with this comment... Obviously https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34906969/does-net-core-generate-the-same-il-as-standard-net … so OP is unlikely asking what output is... but you seem to know exactly what they are asking - care to clarify?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I think I understand what Jeremy is saying.  Since .NET Standard is not an implementation, which library provides an implementation of String.Replace (for instance) when you compile the project in isolation.

Comment: @AngryHacker how that is different for any other compilation in .NET - you pretty much never know what library will provide implementation of methods code in the library refers to... I guess totally misunderstanding your comment... (there is likely interesting question in all it as I did not have a need to dig deep into how it exactly represented in IL... )

Comment: Project build/compilation is just against a set of referenced assemblies, https://blog.lextudio.com/the-rough-history-of-referenced-assemblies-7d752d92c18c where .NET Standard only adds a few more. So what exactly do you want to learn?

Comment: `Project build/compilation is just against a set of referenced assemblies` - Yes. Which ones? .net standard is not supposed to "have" any.

Comment: `you pretty much never know what library will provide implementation of methods code in the library refers to` - I'm asking about those libraries. When compiling the library, when you _are_ supposed to know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(only a partial answer)

Take a look at what is shown when the *Dependencies* node is expanded:

[image]

A .NET Standard library ends up picking an implementation, in this case it is .NET Core.

**Now why .NET Core as opposed to .NET Framework ?**

I guess because it is platform agnostic and thus fits the paradigm of .NET Standard which is about openness, the same could not be said for the .NET Framework.

**And what is the purpose of netstandard.dll ?**

When you open it in the decompiler of your choice, you will see thousands of `TypeForwardedTo` attributes, i.e. its role is to forward .NET Standard types to an implementation.

Also, interestingly, it's not even written by Microsoft but by the Mono development team.

Comment: Nice catch! Now I wonder what will happen when my solution with a .net framework project that references the .net standard project is built. I guess the framework will just have to consume the core.

Comment: When you do such thing, you will see that .NET Framework also has its own implementation of `netstandard.dll`, it sits at `C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\netstandard.dll`. I didn't check but it probably forwards everything to, you guessed it, the .NET framework itself.

Answer (score 1):

[Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard) define .NET Standard as below:

> .NET Standard is a formal specification of .NET APIs that are intended
>   to be available on all .NET implementations. The motivation behind
>   .NET Standard is to establish greater uniformity in the .NET
>   ecosystem. ECMA 335 continues to establish uniformity for .NET
>   implementation behavior, and while ECMA 335 specifies a small set of
>   standard libraries, the .NET Standard specification encompasses a
>   broader range of .NET APIs.

It is **completely possible** to build a .NET Standard project in isolation. But, how it can be consumed really depends on the version you are using. Choosing what version of .NET Standard you want to use depends on your use-case. Higher the version more APIs are available but it also means you can target fewer platforms.

Take a very simple example of .NET Standard 2.0 vs 2.1.

Let us say, you need to create a Client Library/ Nuget package for different applications to consume. If you choose .NET Standard 2.0, your library can be targeted by .NET Core 2.0+ and .NET Framework 4.6.1+ (with some caveats).

If however, you know that you will only have consumers on .NET Core 3.0 and above, it is safe to choose .NET Standard 2.1 as your target and get advantages of additional APIs and features available in the .NET Standard 2.1